# Locking the yaw direction of a laser pointer

Tags: sensors, stability

I have a laser pointer on a handle grip and I'm trying to keep the laser pointer's yaw direction, which can rotate at around 10deg/s. So I have the laser pointer on a stepper motor and an accelerometer/gyro in the handle, but what's a good way for maintaining its yaw direction? Could I simply turn the shaft according to the accelerometer/gyro's yaw readings or is control theory (PID) needed?

That is, if my stepper makes 4096 steps/rev, one gives 0.0879 deg. If the handle is turned by, say, 0.879 deg, then turn 10 steps in reverse (instantaneously). Would this be jerky and PID be needed?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: Define "jerky". How fast are you able to sense and control?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be it is going to be fine if you make sure that the stepper reacts fast enough. Hand motions are naturally jerk (and acceleration) limited, so your reaction will also be -- unless you wait too long and let the error accumulate.

I think that bigger problem might be the noise of your sensors. Some clever filtering might be necessary.